# Alternative way to get QOpenGLFramebufferObject anti-aliased texture other than multisampling + blitting

Tags: c++, qt, opengl-es, windows-ce

I'm trying to achieve anti-aliased effect on the texture of the FBO (`QOpenGLFramebufferObject`) used when doing native GL drawing on a Qt 5.2.1 widget-based application on WinCE-based device. It supports OpenGL ES 2.0.

The mechanism described on Qt documentation using two `QOpenGLFramebufferObject`, one with multi-sample enabled (e.g. 4 samples) and another one without multi-sampling used as the target FBO to down-sample, then blitting from the multi-sampled one to the down-sampled one does not work.

This is because the blit operation is not supported on the device, `QOpenGLFramebufferObject::hasOpenGLFramebufferBlit()` returns false, even though it works properly anti-aliased on Win32 desktop where the blit is supported.

Is there any other way to achieve the anti-aliasing without using this blit operation? Preferably using Qt components to ease the implementation.

**Details on the situation**:
The application displays the GL drawings as the screen background and on top of that the control widgets (buttons, labels, etc.). The GL drawings itself are done by a third party library that we use.

For this we use `QGraphicsView` and `QGraphicsScene` to have the library draws the background and add the control widgets to the scene to be drawn on top of it.

Aside from the `QGLWidget`'s context created for the `QGraphicsView`'s viewport, we have a separate GL context and FBOs created exclusively for the library to use because the library expects an exclusive context for itself. The contexts share display list and texture object and are switched before and after the library draws.

The library draws depending on a `QTimer` callback to simulate the desired frames per second. During the drawing the multi-sampled FBO will be bound and released after the drawing is done, and then blitted to the down-sampled one.

During the `QGraphicsScene::drawBackground()` the texture of the down-sampled FBO will be drawn on the viewport's context using `QGLContext::drawTexture()`. Sadly this draws garbage on the device because the blit operation from the multi to down-sampled FBO is not supported.

Answer (score 2):

ES 2.0 also does not support multisampled textures/renderbuffers that you could use as FBO attachments. At least not without extensions. So it's not only the blit that is missing to support this with ES 2.0.

The easiest solution is to go all the way to full super-sampling. Quality wise, this can be superior to multi-sampling since it does not only smooth polygon edges and intersections. What you do is allocate a texture that is a multiple (typically twice) the size of the final render target. Render to it, and then downsample it with a "blit" you implement yourself with a simple shader.

There's one important caveat: It's very resource hungry. The texture is 4 times the size, so it will use a lot of memory if your render surfaces are moderately large. You'll even have to be careful that you don't exceed the `MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE` limit. Along with the high memory usage goes significantly reduced performance.

There is at least one other option, which is an approach that was used much more commonly before multi-sampling was widely available. The idea is that you render the frame multiple times, with a slight offset, and then average these frames. Looks for "Scene Antialiasing" in the [Red Book](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter10.html) on how this was done with old style OpenGL. The accumulation buffer (and most everything else) used in that code has long been deprecated, but you can implement the same idea with FBOs.

Comment: I also got a suggestion from a colleague to do this super-sampling and map the user events like mouse clicks to the library's render coordinate. I'm hoping that Qt has a trick up the sleeve to do this easier, but if there isn't any other option I'll mark this answer as "the answer".

Comment: Hi Reto, I found out that my device actually support the extension GL_EXT_multisampled_render_to_texture. Do you know if Qt doesn't use this or a way to enforce using this? Thanks before.